# TreeView inside AutoCompleteBox's popup

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, autocompletebox

Inspired by [this post](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2008/11/autocompletebox-missing-guide/), I'm trying to use a TreeView inside the AutoCompleteBox's popup in order to show hierarchical data.

Here's what i did:

1. I Made my own TreeView that implements ISelectionAdapter (not sure it's perfect)
2. Edit AutoCompleteBox template and change the selector to my treeview
3. Try Bind my ViewModel to it

Unfortunately this is not working.
i checked my new TreeView with the same binding to the same object and it works prefectly when it's outside of a AutoCompleteBox template.

Any idea? any special way to implement ISelectionAdapter  for treeview? did i missed something?

couldn't find any example for it on the web...

Thanks.

Comment: I think link you provided is not displaying TreeView or any sort of hierarchy. It is highlighting matching string in the container source.

Comment: Look at the "Templating the control" topic on this page. this is exactly it:

"And, you can re-template to bind to anything you like, add display member bindings, use different controls in the popup (like a TreeView, DataGrid, movie player, etc.). To use your own control inside the drop down, you’ll need to implement the ISelectionAdapter interface or write your own wrapper/adapter for the control to interact with AutoCompleteBox."

Comment: The control was designed to potentially work with TreeView, but it isn't going to be easy to accomplish - you'll need to definitely do SelectionAdapter work. It might be best to have the ACB source code handy and study it a lot, I'm not sure where I would even start off.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, i notice that it is not really straight forward. also i tried to avoid it, i'll probably do something like this http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/AutoCompleteTreeview.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to write it eventually.

Made a custom control for it. it still need to be refined, but it works good:

Generic.xaml :

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="CommonValidationToolTipTemplate" TargetType="ToolTip">
    <Grid x:Name="Root" Margin="5,0" Opacity="0" RenderTransformOrigin="0,0">
        <Grid.RenderTransform>
            <TranslateTransform x:Name="Translation" X="-25"/>
        </Grid.RenderTransform>
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="OpenStates">
                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                    <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0"/>
                    <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.2" To="Open">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.2" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X" Storyboard.TargetName="Translation">
                                <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                    <BackEase Amplitude=".3" EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                                </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                            </DoubleAnimation>
                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.2" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="Root"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualTransition>
                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                <VisualState x:Name="Closed">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="Root"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="Open">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X" Storyboard.TargetName="Translation"/>
                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="Root"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <Border Background="#052A2E31" CornerRadius="5" Margin="4,4,-4,-4"/>
        <Border Background="#152A2E31" CornerRadius="4" Margin="3,3,-3,-3"/>
        <Border Background="#252A2E31" CornerRadius="3" Margin="2,2,-2,-2"/>
        <Border Background="#352A2E31" CornerRadius="2" Margin="1,1,-1,-1"/>
        <Border Background="#FFDC000C" CornerRadius="2">
            <TextBlock Foreground="White" MaxWidth="250" Margin="8,4,8,4" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding (Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}" UseLayoutRounding="false"/>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
<Style TargetType="local:AutoCompleteTreeView"
       xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
        <Setter.Value>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FFA3AEB9" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF8399A9" Offset="0.375"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF718597" Offset="0.375"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF617584" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFFFFFFF"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF000000"/>
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="45"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:AutoCompleteTreeView">
                <Grid Opacity="{TemplateBinding Opacity}">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="PopupStates">
                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.1" To="PopupOpened"/>
                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.2" To="PopupClosed"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualState x:Name="PopupOpened">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation To="1.0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="PopupBorder"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="PopupClosed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation To="0.0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="PopupBorder"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ValidationStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Valid"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="InvalidUnfocused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="ValidationErrorElement">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="InvalidFocused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="ValidationErrorElement">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsOpen" Storyboard.TargetName="validationTooltip">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <System:Boolean>True</System:Boolean>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <TextBox x:Name="Text" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" IsTabStop="True" Margin="0" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Style="{TemplateBinding TextBoxStyle}"/>
                    <Border x:Name="ValidationErrorElement" BorderBrush="#FFDB000C" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="1" Visibility="Collapsed">
                        <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                            <ToolTip x:Name="validationTooltip" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Placement="Right" PlacementTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Template="{StaticResource CommonValidationToolTipTemplate}">
                                <ToolTip.Triggers>
                                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Canvas.Loaded">
                                        <BeginStoryboard>
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsHitTestVisible" Storyboard.TargetName="validationTooltip">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                            <System:Boolean>true</System:Boolean>
                                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </BeginStoryboard>
                                    </EventTrigger>
                                </ToolTip.Triggers>
                            </ToolTip>
                        </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                        <Grid Background="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="12" Margin="1,-4,-4,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="12">
                            <Path Data="M 1,0 L6,0 A 2,2 90 0 1 8,2 L8,7 z" Fill="#FFDC000C" Margin="1,3,0,0"/>
                            <Path Data="M 0,0 L2,0 L 8,6 L8,8" Fill="#ffffff" Margin="1,3,0,0"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <Popup x:Name="Popup">
                        <Grid Opacity="{TemplateBinding Opacity}">
                            <Border x:Name="PopupBorder" BorderThickness="0" Background="#11000000" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Opacity="0">
                                <Border.RenderTransform>
                                    <TranslateTransform X="1" Y="1"/>
                                </Border.RenderTransform>
                                <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Opacity="1.0" Padding="0">
                                    <Border.Background>
                                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                            <GradientStop Color="#FFDDDDDD" Offset="0"/>
                                            <GradientStop Color="#AADDDDDD" Offset="1"/>
                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                    </Border.Background>
                                    <Border.RenderTransform>
                                        <TransformGroup>
                                            <TranslateTransform X="-1" Y="-1"/>
                                        </TransformGroup>
                                    </Border.RenderTransform>
                                    <local:TreeViewSelectionAdapter x:Name="SelectionAdapter" BorderThickness="0" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ItemTemplate="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplate}" ItemContainerStyle="{TemplateBinding ItemContainerStyle}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"/>
                                </Border>  
                            </Border>  
                        </Grid>
                    </Popup>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

AutoCompleteTreeView.cs:

```
public class AutoCompleteTreeView : AutoCompleteBox
{
    public AutoCompleteTreeView()
    {
        DefaultStyleKey = typeof(AutoCompleteTreeView);
    }
}
```

TreeViewSelectionAdapter.cs:

```
public class TreeViewSelectionAdapter : TreeView, ISelectionAdapter
{
    private object lastSelectedItem = null;

    /// <summary>
    ///This prevents the text box of the AutoCompleteBox control from being updated continuously.
    /// </summary>
    private bool IgnoreAnySelection { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// An event that indicates that a selection is complete and has been
    /// made, effectively a commit action.
    /// </summary>
    public event RoutedEventHandler Commit;

    /// <summary>
    /// An event that indicates that the selection operation has been
    /// canceled.
    /// </summary>
    public event RoutedEventHandler Cancel;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the SelectorSelectionAdapter class.
    /// </summary>
    public TreeViewSelectionAdapter()
    {
        base.SelectedItemChanged += new RoutedPropertyChangedEventHandler<object>(OnSelectionChanged);
        MouseLeftButtonUp += OnSelectorMouseLeftButtonUp;

    }

    void OnSelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
    {

        if (IgnoreAnySelection)
        {
            return;
        }

        SelectionChangedEventHandler handler = this.SelectionChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            IList oldSelectedItem = new List<object>();
            if (lastSelectedItem != null)
                oldSelectedItem.Add(lastSelectedItem);

            if (SelectionChanged != null)
                handler(this, new SelectionChangedEventArgs(oldSelectedItem, new List<object> { this.SelectedItem }));

            lastSelectedItem = this.SelectedItem;

        }
    }

    public new object SelectedItem
    {
        get
        {
            return base.SelectedItem;
        }

        set
        {
            this.SelectItem(value);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handles the mouse left button up event on the selector control.
    /// </summary>
    private void OnSelectorMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        IgnoreAnySelection = false;

        OnSelectionChanged(this, null);
        OnCommit(this, new RoutedEventArgs());
    }


    public event SelectionChangedEventHandler SelectionChanged;



    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the items source.
    /// </summary>
    public new IEnumerable ItemsSource
    {
        get { return base.ItemsSource; }

        set
        {
            if (base.ItemsSource != null)
            {
                INotifyCollectionChanged notify = base.ItemsSource as INotifyCollectionChanged;
                if (notify != null)
                {
                    notify.CollectionChanged -= OnCollectionChanged;
                }
            }

            base.ItemsSource = value;

            if (base.ItemsSource != null)
            {
                INotifyCollectionChanged notify = base.ItemsSource as INotifyCollectionChanged;
                if (notify != null)
                {
                    notify.CollectionChanged += OnCollectionChanged;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handles the CollectionChanged event, resetting the selection
    /// ignore flag.
    /// </summary>
    private void OnCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        IgnoreAnySelection = true;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Process a key down event.
    /// </summary>
    public void HandleKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Key)
        {
            case Key.Enter:
                IgnoreAnySelection = false;
                OnCommit(this, e);
                e.Handled = true;
                break;


            case Key.Down:
                if ((ModifierKeys.Alt & Keyboard.Modifiers) == ModifierKeys.None)
                {
                    IgnoreAnySelection = true;
                    //SelectedIndexIncrement();
                    TreeView tv = this.FindName("SelectionAdapter") as TreeView;

                    tv.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(tv_KeyDown);
                    tv.Focus();

                    List<TreeViewItem> ls = new List<TreeViewItem>(tv.GetContainers());
                    ls[0].Focus();
                    e.Handled = true;

                }
                break;

            case Key.Escape:
                OnCancel(this, e);
                e.Handled = true;
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    void tv_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Key)
        {
            case Key.Enter:

                IgnoreAnySelection = false;

                OnSelectionChanged(this, null);
                OnCommit(this, new RoutedEventArgs());
                break;
        }
    }



    /// <summary>
    /// Fires the Commit event.
    /// </summary>
    private void OnCommit(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        RoutedEventHandler handler = Commit;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(sender, e);
        }

        AfterAdapterAction();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Fires the Cancel event.
    /// </summary>
    private void OnCancel(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        RoutedEventHandler handler = Cancel;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(sender, e);
        }

        AfterAdapterAction();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Change the selection after the actions are complete.
    /// </summary>
    private void AfterAdapterAction()
    {
        this.SetSelectedContainer(null);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of a DataGridAutomationPeer.
    /// </summary>
    public AutomationPeer CreateAutomationPeer()
    {
        return new TreeViewAutomationPeer(this);
    }
}
```

Using the control:

```
<ccontrols:AutoCompleteTreeView  x:Name="textbox" MinimumPrefixLength="1" IsEnabled="True" ItemsSource="{Binding MyNodes}"  >
        <ccontrols:AutoCompleteTreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <hirarch:HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding MyNodes}" >
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </hirarch:HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </ccontrols:AutoCompleteTreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </ccontrols:AutoCompleteTreeView>
```

The hierarchy objects:

```
public class Node
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Node> MyNodes { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
```